# IE - how to read client image file as base64

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, io, fileapi, shim

I am quite interested to know if there is a way to read local files with IE8 (as FF File API does)? I mean read an image file with Internet Explorer 8 and convert it to base64 encoding then assign it to a JavaScript variable.

I know there is a way in FF, but is it possible with IE8? I couldn't find any complete snippets showing the effect, so any useful tutorial is much appreciated :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Enable JavaScript file API in IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140105/how-to-enable-javascript-file-api-in-ie8)

Answer (score 0):

IE can make an AJAX request to get a binary stream, but it has to be on the [same domain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms759211) or go through a [server-side proxy](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/296772)

Comment: I meant a client machine IO in IE :)