# How to Enable JavaScript file API in IE8

Tags: javascript, asp.net, browser, internet-explorer-8

I have developed a web application in asp.net, there is a page in this project which user should choose a file in picture format (jpeg, jpg, bmp,...) and I want to preview image in the page but I don't want to post file to server I want to handle it in client i have done it with java scripts functions via file API but it only works in IE9 but most of the costumers use IE8 the  reason is that IE8 doesn't support file API is there any way to make IE8 upgrade or some patches in code behind I mean that check if the browser is IE and not support file API call a function which upgrades IE8 to IE9 automatically.

I don't want to ask user to do it in message I want to do it programmatically!!
even if it is possible to install a special patch that is required for file API
because customers thought it is a bug in my application and their computer knowledge is low 
what am I supposed to do with this?
I also use Async File Upload Ajax Control But it post the file to server any way  with ajax solution and HTTP handler but java scripts do it all in client browser!!!
following script checks the browser supports API or not

```
<script>
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) 
  document.write("<b>File API supported.</b>");
else
  document.write('<i>File API not supported by this browser.</i>');
</script>
```

following scripts do the read and Load Image

```
function readfile(e1)
{
  var filename = e1.target.files[0]; 
  var fr = new FileReader();
   fr.onload = readerHandler;  
  fr.readAsText(filename); 
}
```

HTML code:

```
<input type="file" id="getimage">

<fieldset><legend>Your image here</legend>
    <div  id="imgstore"></div>
</fieldset>
```

JavaScript code:

```
<script>
function imageHandler(e2) 
{ 
  var store = document.getElementById('imgstore');
  store.innerHTML='<img src="' + e2.target.result +'">';
}

function loadimage(e1)
{
  var filename = e1.target.files[0]; 
  var fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = imageHandler;  
  fr.readAsDataURL(filename); 
}

window.onload=function()
{
  var x = document.getElementById("filebrowsed");
  x.addEventListener('change', readfile, false);
  var y = document.getElementById("getimage");
  y.addEventListener('change', loadimage, false);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't *install* anything special to add support for File API in IE8. What you can do is use a **polyfill** in order to implement this functionality in browsers that don't natively support it. Take a look at this list of [HTML5 Cross Browser Polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) (you should find something suitable for you in *File API / Drag and Drop* section).

Comment: Thanks a lot tpeczek i will check it out, Polyfill  function needs  flash to run so i should ask user to download and install flash and  i don't want to ask user to do any thing because user may can install IE9 any way in software when developers see a bug they release a patch or a plug-in which corrects bug you know i want to copy a DLL file in explorer directory and do some changes to explorer via any kind of scripts i think there is a way that i can upload a file and check if the browser doesn't supports the API function download DLL file and do some operation like copy to system32

Comment: My big problem is that IE8 doesn't support File API any way even a batch file to do some thing

Comment: @saeed The only way to get File API supported in IE is to have IE9+. You also can't change any DLL or install any software from web application level - such a possibility would be a huge security breach (remember that you are in a sandbox).

Comment: you mean that there is no way! -> so how can i preview image to user in ie8 no uploading i want to first preview image and then post it to a web service via byte array and saves it to DB

Comment: @saeed Yes, as I said in the answer

Comment: you mean that there is no way! -> so how can i preview image to user in ie8 no uploading i want to first preview image and then post it to a web service via byte array and saves it to DB

Comment: any reference that guides me to do so

Comment: @saeed The only way for doing this without uploading to the sever for browsers which doesn't support File API is using ActiveX or Flash. The best approach is the one I have described in the answer - you check if the browser supports File API (you know how to do this) and if no you load the polyfill of your choosing. The rest of code is the same as you have the same API available after loading a polyfill.

Comment: i agree you but you said that it is not permitted in application level because of security issue but i have seen sites which could upgrade motherboard bios software through page am i right?

Comment: again i have seen some pages which could change display resolution but i don't know how they do that off course they might use ActiveX

Comment: any way thanks for your attention i hope so there should be some possibility because of security reasons the computers which runs application are not able to install any software but there is only way is to upload a copy of software like flash or IE9 on their local intranet and run it.

Comment: the company wants to develop a web application which works with browser that comes with windows as i mentioned they don't want additional software but i want to do it in a way that they don't understand what happens if i could upgrade them to IE9+ in a hidden way or may be with a batch file problem is solved.Thanks in advance

Comment: in my latest search found the following link is it use full what you think ? is it possible to use WMI 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation#Importance_of_WMI_providers
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302051.aspx

Comment: @saeed You are still going in wrong direction. If the client requirement for application is to work on IE8 you should make it so and use some ActiveX or upload image to some temp location in your application. You should stop trying to *hack* end user systems in order to get you enviroment which you want.

Comment: HTML 5 is not supported by IE8. There is addons  for Canvas, and also there is Google Chrome Frame, a plugin to add HTML 5 to IE older than 9. i will post details later.

Comment: if you think this question is useful for others please vote it up :^)

Comment: @saeed - If you can share the solution for this, it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

After some researches i have got there is no way to Enable file API in IE8 but, i got some thing that want to share it with you .....
Not directly, HTML 5 is not supported by IE8. There is addons  for Canvas, and also there is Google Chrome Frame, a plugin to add HTML 5 to IE older than 9.
As i understood , Google Chrome Frame is perfect way to use HTML5.
It increases IE speed 10 times and also it's usage is very easy and i describe it for you all members...
Google Chrome Frame

A plugin for Internet Explorer that add to the Microsoft's browser, a full HTML 5 support and the JavaScript compiler of Chrome!
A stable version was released on September 22, 2010 and a lot of sites have added the code in their pages.

This plugin will work on Internet Explorer 6, 7 and further versions. Google wants to break a barrier that prevents the Web to evolve: the most common browser and its lack of compatibility with the new standards.

When it is recognized, Internet Explorer will run under WebKit, the rendering engine of Chrome and Safari, and the it will use the ultra-fast JavaScript compiler in replacement if the IE interpreter.

The advantage of this plugin is great for the compatibility of web applications and will become even more useful with WebGL integrated in Webkit, which let us have applications in 3D on the browser: a very different Web! 
WebGL is also supported by Firefox since the version 3.7.

Since May 2011, the plugin can be installed without administrator rights, so on older version of IE which are incorporated into a server and can not be updated.

A tag in the code of a Web page will display a message prompting the user to download the plugin. Once it is installed, IE run as Chrome and will support HTML 5.

Features of Frame

The off-line mode.
The  and  tags. Microsoft also plans to implement them in IE.
Canvas.
WebGL.
CSS 3.
JavaScript compiler.
Compatibility at Acid 3 level.
See the vidéo.

Reaction from Microsoft

We were expecting that Microsoft has not appreciated really this initiative that promotes HTML 5 to the detriment of their own solution, Silverlight. The firm highlights a security problem:

Given the security issues with plug-ins in general and Google Chrome in particular, Google Chrome Frame running as a plug-in has doubled the attack area for malware and malicious scripts.

**

> Chrome Frame. Automatic install. ->
>   http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?quickenable=true 
>  Google Chrome
>   Frame code. -> https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/ 
>   Chrome Frame: Developer Guide. -> http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started

**

Comment: Google Chrome Frame support is shutting down. From the website: "We're winding down Chrome Frame, and plan to cease support and updates in January 2014."

Answer (score 2):

This works for me in pre IE10, i use https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js for every other browser, note though this works it's not perfect, because it's IE and well you know what I mean

Hope this helps

```
/**
 * saves File, pops up a built in javascript file as a download
 * @param {String} filename, eg doc.csv
 * @param {String} filecontent eg "this","is","csv"
 * @param {String} mimetype eg "text/plain"
 */
function saveAs (filename, filecontent, mimetype) {
    var w = window.open();
    var doc = w.document;
    doc.open( mimetype,'replace');
    doc.charset = "utf-8";
    doc.write(filecontent);
    doc.close();
    doc.execCommand("SaveAs", null, filename);
}
```

Comment: great but the question is for ie8. So the library is useless at its best.

Comment: worked for me for a project in IE8, i've also in other projects shimmed the downloading of files to a 'post' rpc end point that reflects a provided binary string as a download with a provided mime type, which works really well

Comment: then I guess you have to edit you post. Include that it works for ie8.

Comment: i did, eg PRE-IE10 :)