# Javascript FileReader on IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have this javascript function which shows a preview after user picked an image. My problem is that it's not working on IE and I do not figure out why.

No error, but input.files is null.

The JavaScript

```
function showimagepreview(input, previewId) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var filerdr = new FileReader();
        filerdr.onload = function (e) {
            $('#' + previewId).attr('src', e.target.result);
        }
        filerdr.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

this is my HTML code

```
<div class="photo" id="photo-1">
    <input type="file" class="upload-file" name="Photos[1]" onchange="showimagepreview(this, 'photosPreview1')" />
    <img id="photosPreview1" class="PhotoPreview" />
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, IE8 does not support FileReader (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140105/how-to-enable-javascript-file-api-in-ie8).

Comment: you can always [cheat](https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/).

Comment: No you can't: "Google Chrome Frame is no longer supported and retired as of February 25, 2014."

Comment: @CaseyFalk Yeah they discontinued it, but you can [still find](https://2ra5-downloads.phpnuke.org/en/c152100/google-chrome-frame#.U8Z8e3WSzQo) it [around](http://google-chrome-frame.en.softonic.com/), and host it for your users yourself

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `FileReader` is not compatible with IE8.

See [here](http://caniuse.com/filereader) for a comprehensive list of browser support for this functionality.

Comment: Yes the FileReader was not even a specification or draft back in 2007 when IE 8 was being built.

Answer (score 1):

As explain previously IE 8 Doesn't support FileReader API http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader

But you can use a polyfill !
Moxie can solve your problem.
https://github.com/moxiecode/moxie

Answer (score 0):

IE 8 does not support `FileReader`.

Try using [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/). I guess you can get it working with it.