# Issues in Uploading File using ajax in IE7 and IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, fileapi

I'm trying to upload a file in IE7 and IE8 browser using FileAPI library, but unfortunately it is not working. It is working in all the other browser but not in IE7, IE8 and it is my business requirement to make it work in IE7, IE8 too.
Here is my js code

```
jQuery(function ($){

    $(document)
        .on('click', '.imageLabel', function (evt){
            imageUploadId = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[1];
            previewImage = document.getElementById('previewHolderDiv_' + imageUploadId);
            $("#imageError_" + imageUploadId).html("");
            errorMessageUl = document.getElementById('imageError_' + imageUploadId);
            removeImageIcon = document.getElementById('removeImage_' + imageUploadId);
        })



        var form = document.forms.vehicleDocumentForm;

        var input = form.vehicleImage;


        var uploadOpts = {
            url: '/save-vehicle-document',
            data: {},
            name: 'vehicleImage',
            activeClassName: 'upload_active' 
        };


        var _onSelectFile = function (evt/**Event*/){

            var file = FileAPI.getFiles(evt)[0];

            if( file ){
                _uploadFile(file, imageUploadId);
            }
        };

        var _uploadFile = function (file){

            uploadOpts.data = {"imageId" : imageUploadId};            
            var opts = FileAPI.extend(uploadOpts, {
                files: {},


                upload: function (){
                    form.className += ' '+uploadOpts.activeClassName;
                },


                complete: function (err, xhr){
                    //enableSellYourButtons();
                    form.className = (' '+form.className+' ').replace(' '+uploadOpts.activeClassName+' ', ' ');
                    var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    if( response.result == "fail"){
                        previewImage.html = "";
                        $("#imageError_" + imageUploadId).html("<li>" + response.message + "</li>");
                    } else {
                        $("#imageError_" + imageUploadId).html("");
                        $("#vehicleImageName_" + imageUploadId).attr("value", response.message);
                    }
                }
            });


            opts.files[opts.name] = file;


            FileAPI.upload(opts);
        };


        FileAPI.event.on(input, "change", _onSelectFile);
}); // ready
```

I'm getting an error
SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action

File: FileAPI.min.js, Line: 2, Column: 11608

My FileAPI version is 2.0.11

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You should check [this topic][1] on SO.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140105/how-to-enable-javascript-file-api-in-ie8

Answer (score 0):

According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=File), the FileApi is not compatible with IE7/8.

Comment: Do you know any other js library or plugin that uses ajax to upload file and works in IE7 and IE8?