# Displaying Fileupload image using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Code:

```
<input type="file" name="filUpload" id="filUpload" onchange="showimagepreview(this)" />

<img id="imgprvw" alt="uploaded image preview"/>
```

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showimagepreview(input) {

            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var filerdr = new FileReader();
                filerdr.onload = function (e) {

                    $('#imgprvw').attr('src', e.target.result);
                }
                filerdr.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

I want to display the fileupload image using Jquery.

This Code is working fine in Chrome but not in IE. Please help.

Comment: Most probably the version of IE you are using does not support `FileReader`. For more info and alternative take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140105/how-to-enable-javascript-file-api-in-ie8